# Unable to connect to websocket on spring AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer

Tags: spring, websocket

A request to

```
http://localhost:8080/chat/info
```

gives

```
{"entropy":1407128458,"origins":["*:*"],"cookie_needed":true,"websocket":true}
```

But websocket server is undefined when i try to use it

Using:
Spring Boot
Embedded tomcat 
    @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
    ...

```
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/chat").withSockJS();
}
```

[image: issue explained in screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are enabling `SockJS` on your server side but using the plain WebSocket API on your client side, use the [sockjs client library](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client) instead. Replace:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/chat");
```

with:

```
var socket = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/chat");
```